# How can I catch and re-use values obtained in a loop of ParDo transformations in Apache Beam?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to create a pipeline that reads from an API and writes into BigQuery. The problem is that I need to make multiple API calls since the response on the endpoint is limited to 150 results.

The API response has the following structure

`{'rows'='<list of dictionaries containing the data>', 'pagination'='<String that is used as a parameter to make the new API call and keed receiving results>'}`

This is my code:

```
HEADER = {"x-api-key": API_KEY}

class CallAPI(beam.DoFn):
   def __init__(self, input_header):
       self.headers = input_header
      
   def process(self, input_uri):
    res = requests.get(input_uri), headers=self.headers)
    res.raise_for_status()
    data = res.json()
    for record in data['data']:
      yield record

with beam.Pipeline() as p:    
      data = (
          p
          | beam.Create([URI])
          | 'Call API ' >> beam.ParDo(CallAPI(HEADER))
          | ...
```

Right now, I am returning the rows that I need to write using `yield record`. But I need to create a for loop that makes multiple calls and uses the pagination result obtained on the previous call to make a new one. Anybody knows how to save and use results obtained in previous runs? Thank you

Comment: You probably want to use [states](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#state-and-timers) here.